# Why is my app setting not being retained?

Tags: c#, wpf, appsettings

I'm trying to save a simple app setting ("LanguagePairId") this way:

```
if (rdbtnEnglishPersian.IsChecked == true) // because "IsChecked" is a nullable bool, the "== true" is necessary
{
    langPairId = 1;
}
else if (rdbtnEnglishGerman.IsChecked == true)
{
    langPairId = 2;
}
else if (rdbtnEnglishSpanish.IsChecked == true)
{
    langPairId = 3;
}
else if (rdbtnGermanSpanish.IsChecked == true)
{
    langPairId = 4;
}
else if (rdbtnGermanPersian.IsChecked == true)
{
    langPairId = 5;
}
else if (rdbtnSpanishPersian.IsChecked == true)
{
    langPairId = 6;
}
AppSettings.Default.LanguagePairId = langPairId;
```

LanguagePairId is being assigned the expected value (if rdbtnEnglishSpanish is checked, it is assigned 3, etc.)

But trying to read the app setting value on app startup:

```
int langPairId;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RecheckTheLastSelectedRadBtn();
}

private void RecheckTheLastSelectedRadBtn()
{
    langPairId = AppSettings.Default.LanguagePairId;
    switch (langPairId)
    {
        case 1:
            rdbtnEnglishPersian.IsChecked = true;
            break;
            . . .
```

...fails -- AppSettings.Default.LanguagePairId is seen as 0 on restaring the app. Why? What must I do to get the value to be saved and restored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a call to `AppSettings.Default.Save()` anywhere.

Without that, your changes to the settings won't be saved.

Try adding it immediately after you set the property. E.g.:

```
AppSettings.Default.LanguagePairId = langPairId;
AppSettings.Default.Save();
```